# Quickly adding a category to a message

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba, microsoft-outlook-2010, tags

This may sound stupid but solving the problem would save me a lot of time.
I am big on using categories (in place of folders, pretty much like labeling an email under Gmail), and more often than not I merely assign the same categories of emails I already sorted out to emails I receive. Doing it by hand is time-consuming, and I'd like to simply use 'quick step' or a VBA macro to have the following job done:

1 - selecting one email without category and one with them
2 - copying categories of the second one and pasting them into the first one

Has anybody worked on something even remotely resembling that type of task?
I thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

For Outlook 2013:

- go to Categorize dropdown in the Ribbon and select All Categories.
- Select your category
- In the Shortcut Key dropdown on the right, select one of the pre-defined shortcut key

Not sure if this is available in earlier versions of Outlook.

[image: All Categories]

[image: Shortcut]

Answer (score 0):

Attached picture details the kind of problem I'm routinely dealing with.
One email has all the categories I assigned, a newly arrived one has none.
Clicking on 'Categorize' gives what the forefront square picture shows : eg one email is categorized 'coupon' the other one is not (hence the aspect of the box next to the category : not checked but not blank either).

I'd like the VBA macro to rapidly copy/paste categories.
Hope this clarifies my first post.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFAGg.jpg)